# Applicative form in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

I have defined `Wff` data type:

```
data Wff = P Text | Ng Wff | Box Wff | Cnj [Wff] | Dsj [Wff] 
    deriving (Eq)

instance  Show Wff where
    show (P name) = unpack $ name
    show (Ng f) = "-" ++ show f
    show (Box f) = "[]" ++ show f
    show (Cnj[]) = show " "
    show (Cnj[f]) = show f
    show (Cnj (f:fs)) = "(" ++ show f ++ "&" ++  show (Cnj fs) ++ ")"
    show(Dsj[]) = show " "
    show(Dsj[f]) = show f
    show (Dsj (f:fs)) = "(" ++ show f ++ "v" ++ show (Dsj fs) ++ ")"
```

A function that translates a string to `Wff`:

```
foo :: String -> Wff
foo xs | elem '|' xs =  Dsj (map foo (splitOn "|" xs))
foo xs | elem '&' xs =  Cnj (map foo (splitOn "&" xs))
foo xs | head xs == '~' = Ng (foo . tail $ xs)
foo xs | take 2 xs == "[]" = Box (foo . tail . tail $ xs)
foo xs | otherwise = P (pack xs)
```

I am trying to write an app, where a user submits a string in a form and gets `show` of a `Wff` which  corresponds to the string typed by the user. Here's my code:

```
data App = App

mkYesod "App" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
/person PersonR POST
|]

instance Yesod App

instance RenderMessage App FormMessage where
    renderMessage _ _ = defaultFormMessage

instance YesodJquery App

wffAForm :: AForm Handler Wff
wffAForm = (foo. unpack) <$> areq textField "Model" Nothing


wffForm :: Html -> MForm Handler (FormResult Wff, Widget)
wffForm = renderTable wffAForm

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    (widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost wffForm
    defaultLayout
        [whamlet|
        <p> Type your formula </p>
        <form method=post action=@{PersonR} enctype=#{enctype}>
        ^{widget}
        <button>Submit
        |]


postPersonR :: Handler Html
postPersonR = do
    ((result, widget), enctype) <- runFormPost wffForm
    case result of
        FormSuccess wff -> defaultLayout[whamlet| |<p>#{show wff}|]

main :: IO ()
main = warp 3000 App
```

The code compiles and the result is a web-page with the form, but the submit button doesn't do anything. What's wrong with it?

UPD: I looked at the terminal and it is seen that POSt requests don't even been sending for some reason when I click Submit button.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but **1.** `show` should give valid Haskell code as the result. In your case it's not far, but you should probably not use unary `-` and I would change `&` and `v` to `∧` (U+2227 LOGICAL AND) and `∨` (U+2228 LOGICAL OR). **2.** `foo` should be a parser, those are much easier to implement with a suitable parser-combinator library like [megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec).

Answer (score 0):

The submit button should be properly indented under the form element or add a `form` attribute to it.

```
...
defaultLayout
        [whamlet|
        <p> Type your formula </p>
        <form method=post action=@{PersonR} enctype=#{enctype}>
          ^{widget}
          <button>Submit
        |]
...
```

or

```
...
defaultLayout
        [whamlet|
        <p> Type your formula </p>
        <form #myForm method=post action=@{PersonR} enctype=#{enctype}>
          ^{widget}
        <button type=submit form="myForm">Submit
        |]
...
```

`^{widget}` should also be indented relative to the `form` tag.